# Close my spans when I click on my a inside my menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I made a responsive menu a few days ago, it's working pretty well except when I click my a inside the menu-ul I created, it closes the menu but not the state of my burger menu spans.

Here is the code so you can understand

```js
function openNav(){
    document.getElementById('menu-ul').classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid; 
}

#back-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 14px;
  z-index: 9995;
  width: 35px; 
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Agency FB', arial;
  line-height: 32px;
  background: #22cfb5;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transition:background-color .5s;
  -ms-transition:background-color .5s;
  -moz-transition:background-color .5s;
  -webkit-transition:background-color .5s;
   transition:background-color .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#back-top:hover {
  background: #4c4bbf;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navcontainer {
  background-color: #4c4bbf;
}

.menu span {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff; 
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s 
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s 
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
  transition-property: transform, background, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.55s;
  transition-timing-function:
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
  ease;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

.menu input {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 13px; 
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

.menu input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

.menu input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 60.625rem 33.75rem 102.6875rem 103.75rem 74.375rem 11.1875rem;
    gap: 0px 20px;
  }

  header {
    grid-column: 1 / span 6;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1; 
  } 

  #navcontainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem;
    column-gap: 10px;
    place-items: center;
  }

  .logo {
    grid-column: 1 / span 5; 
  }

  .menu {
    grid-column: 6 / span 1;
  }

  #menu-ul {
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#6633ff,#6666ff);
    z-index: 9998;
    grid-column: 1 / span 6; 
    grid-row: 1 / span 7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: -767px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 60.625rem 33.75rem 102.6875rem 103.75rem 74.375rem 11.1875rem;
    gap: 0px 20px;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
  }

  #menu-ul.open {
    left: 0px;
  }

  ul {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 
    4.375rem;
    place-items: center;
  }

  .menu input:checked~#menu-ul {
    transform: translateX(767px);
  }

  .a-menu1 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu2 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu3 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu4 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 4 / span 3;
  }

  #linkedin-menu {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 6  / span 2;
  }

  #insta-menu {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    grid-column: 4 / span 3;
    grid-row: 6  / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#" id="back-top" title="Back top">></a>
    <header>
        <nav role="navigation" id="navcontainer">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="../logo_249.png">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="openNav()"/>
                <span id="span1"></span>
                <span id="span2"></span>
                <span id="span3"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
     <div id="menu-ul">
        <ul>
            <a class="a-menu1" href="#bienvenue" onclick="openNav()"><li>À propos</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu2" href="#services" onclick="openNav()"><li>Mes services</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu3" href="#projets" onclick="openNav()"><li>Mes projets</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu4" href="#contact" onclick="openNav()"><li>Contact</li></a>
            <img src="img/linkedin-white.png" id="linkedin-menu">
            <img src="img/insta-white.png" id="insta-menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can someone help me with this? I already checked some subjects close to mine, but didn't find the answer resolving my problem. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's happening because your checkbox is not unchecked, if you click on menu item. You can modify function like this:

```
function openNav(){
  const menuUl = document.getElementById('menu-ul');
  const burger = document.getElementById('burger');

  if (menuUl.classList.contains('open')) {
        burger.checked = false;
  }
    
  menuUl.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

And add id-attribute to input[type="checkbox"]:

```
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" onclick="openNav()"/>
```

I hope, this will help you!

Comment: That works perfectly! I tried to made my label unchecked by some tricks but didn't managed to do it, you helped me a lot, I will now try to understand what you gave me later when I'm less tired, so I can do it on my own next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by small changes as below.

Step 1: Create a function **toggleMenu()** to toggle the checkbox which is responsible for for the animation.

Step 2: add the above function to all anchor tags as **onclick="toggleMenu()"**.

Please check the **Demo**.

```js
function openNav(){
    document.getElementById('menu-ul').classList.toggle("open");
}

function toggleMenu() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = !document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
    openNav();
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid; 
}

#back-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 14px;
  z-index: 9995;
  width: 35px; 
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Agency FB', arial;
  line-height: 32px;
  background: #22cfb5;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transition:background-color .5s;
  -ms-transition:background-color .5s;
  -moz-transition:background-color .5s;
  -webkit-transition:background-color .5s;
   transition:background-color .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#back-top:hover {
  background: #4c4bbf;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navcontainer {
  background-color: #4c4bbf;
}

.menu span {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff; 
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s 
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s 
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
  transition-property: transform, background, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.55s;
  transition-timing-function:
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
  cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
  ease;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

.menu input {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 13px; 
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

.menu input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

.menu input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 60.625rem 33.75rem 102.6875rem 103.75rem 74.375rem 11.1875rem;
    gap: 0px 20px;
  }

  header {
    grid-column: 1 / span 6;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1; 
  } 

  #navcontainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem;
    column-gap: 10px;
    place-items: center;
  }

  .logo {
    grid-column: 1 / span 5; 
  }

  .menu {
    grid-column: 6 / span 1;
  }

  #menu-ul {
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#6633ff,#6666ff);
    z-index: 9998;
    grid-column: 1 / span 6; 
    grid-row: 1 / span 7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: -767px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 60.625rem 33.75rem 102.6875rem 103.75rem 74.375rem 11.1875rem;
    gap: 0px 20px;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
  }

  #menu-ul.open {
    left: 0px;
  }

  ul {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 4.375rem 
    4.375rem;
    place-items: center;
  }

  .menu input:checked~#menu-ul {
    transform: translateX(767px);
  }

  .a-menu1 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu2 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu3 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
  }

  .a-menu4 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 4 / span 3;
  }

  #linkedin-menu {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 6  / span 2;
  }

  #insta-menu {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    grid-column: 4 / span 3;
    grid-row: 6  / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#" id="back-top" title="Back top">></a>
    <header>
        <nav role="navigation" id="navcontainer">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="../logo_249.png">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="openNav()"/>
                <span id="span1"></span>
                <span id="span2"></span>
                <span id="span3"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
     <div id="menu-ul">
        <ul>
            <a class="a-menu1" href="#bienvenue" onclick="toggleMenu()"><li>À propos</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu2" href="#services" onclick="toggleMenu()"><li>Mes services</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu3" href="#projets" onclick="toggleMenu()"><li>Mes projets</li></a>
            <a class="a-menu4" href="#contact" onclick="toggleMenu()"><li>Contact</li></a>
            <img src="img/linkedin-white.png" id="linkedin-menu">
            <img src="img/insta-white.png" id="insta-menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```